# How to return user email from a custom column "Owner" to an XML from sharepoint online list using CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, email, person-or-group

How to return user email from a custom column "Owner" to an XML from SharePoint online list using CSOM?

This works but bug exists as it sends `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue[]` instead of sending user name /email.

Please help with this bug:

```
string xmlFile = @"c:\temp\export.xml";
Web web = clientContext.Web;
                    ListCollection listColl = web.Lists;
                    List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Site Pages");
                    clientContext.Load(list);
                    FieldCollection listFields = list.Fields;
                    clientContext.Load(listFields);
                    clientContext.Load(listColl);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
                    clientContext.Load(listItems);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    XmlDeclaration declaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "ISO-8859-1", null);
                    doc.AppendChild(declaration);
                    XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("SitePages"); //CREATES FIRST ROOT NODE
                    

                    foreach (ListItem item in listItems)
                    {                    
                        ListItem LItem = listItems.GetById(item.Id);
                        XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("List");                
                      elem.SetAttribute("Owner", Convert.ToString(item["Owner"]));                   // bug exists as it sends Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue[] instead of sending user name /email
                        elem.SetAttribute("ContentNumber", Convert.ToString(item["ContentNumber"]));                       
                        elem.SetAttribute("ID", Convert.ToString(item.Id));
                        root.AppendChild(elem);

                    }
                    doc.AppendChild(root);
                    doc.Save(xmlFile);
                    Console.WriteLine(" XML file is successfully generated");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the email address of user using `web.EnsureUser()` method.

Try using this inside loop:

```
FieldUserValue [] ownerValue = item["Owner"]  as FieldUserValue[];
var ownerUser = web.SiteUsers.GetById(ownerValue[0].LookupId);
context.Load(ownerUser);
context.ExecuteQuery();

Console.WriteLine(ownerUser.Email);
```

For more information, check below references.

**References**:

1. [How to get email address from PeoplePicker field using C# and Client Object model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608726/how-to-get-email-addres-from-peoplepicker-field-using-c-sharp-and-client-object)
2. [Get the mail address from a FieldUserValue Client Side vs Server Side](https://crawlspaceofprogramming.blogspot.com/2015/08/get-mail-address-from-fielduservalue.html)

Comment: Thnaks Ganesh! I tried that but I see run time exception "The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested." can you  help what I am missing?

Comment: Did you use the exact same code as in my answer with `context.Load(ownerUser);
context.ExecuteQuery();`?

Comment: I misspelled column name. It worked thanks :)

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Comment: But i cant pass this value to setattribute